# Smoothly resize minimap camera rect width and height

Tags: unity, c#, camera

I have an orthographic camera that is working as a mini-map. Now I want to make it resizeable using mouse drag. I have applied some UI beside my minimap camera rect and those UI resizing perfectly with this code. But I have no clue that how to resize my camera rect with mouse drag:

```
 void Awake()
    {
        rectTransform = transform.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data)
    {
        if (!resizePanelFeatureActive) return;
        rectTransform.SetAsLastSibling();
        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(rectTransform, data.position, data.pressEventCamera, out previousPointerPosition);
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData data)
    {
        if (!resizePanelFeatureActive) return;

        if (rectTransform == null)
            return;

        Vector2 sizeDelta = rectTransform.sizeDelta;

        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(rectTransform, data.position, data.pressEventCamera, out currentPointerPosition);
        Vector2 resizeValue = currentPointerPosition - previousPointerPosition;

        sizeDelta += new Vector2(resizeValue.x, resizeValue.y);
        sizeDelta = new Vector2(
               Mathf.Clamp(sizeDelta.x, minSize.x, maxSize.x),
               Mathf.Clamp(sizeDelta.y, minSize.y, maxSize.y)
               );

        rectTransform.sizeDelta = sizeDelta;

        previousPointerPosition = currentPointerPosition;
    }
```